# Getting issued certificates' info from windows server 2008 CA

Tags: security, windows-server-2008, certificate-authority

Is it possible to query certificate store on windows server 2008 using .net platform?
I would like to get information about certificates that were issued by this system.

tnx
grega g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With "issued certificates", do you mean certs that have been issued *by* this box, or *to* this box?

Anyway, something like this should get you started playing around with certificate stores:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

class CertificateStoreSample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root);

        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        foreach (X509Certificate certificate in store.Certificates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(certificate.Subject);
        }

        store.Close();
    }
}
```